# Using Python @property without setter

Tags: python, decorator

The code is from this [programiz tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property).

This is the code, removing some lines for cleaner view:

```py
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature=0):
        self.temperature = temperature

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("Getting value...")
        return self._temperature

    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        print("Setting value...")
        self._temperature = value


human = Celsius(37)
print(human.temperature)
human.temperature = 40
```

and its output:

```
Setting value...
Getting value...
37
Setting value...
```

However, if I comment out the `@temperature.setter` decorator, the output is just one line:

```
37
```

Why isn't the `Getting value...` line printed?

Comment: You should be initializing `self._temperature = temperature` in the init (note you missed the leading underscore).

Comment: Because if you comment out the `@temperature.setter`, then `def temperature(self, value)` *overwrites the property with the method*, and then, in your `__init__`, `self.temperature = temperature` *shadows the method with the integer you passed in*.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the "Descriptor".

If you have @setter then the property is a "data descriptor". If you do not have @setter then the property is a "non-data descriptor".

When you call a property from instance. The order the was called is "data descriptor>instance dictionary>non-data descriptor".

So it will call the property in

```
    def __init__(self, temperature=0):
        self.temperature = temperature
```

It will not step into temperature funcion.

By the way, you should check about this https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: If you comment out the `@setter.temperature` *there is no more descriptor class attribute* because `def temperature` overwrites it